# Winefish autocompletion problem

Tags: editors, ubuntu, linux

My OS is ubuntu. [Winefish](http://winefish.berlios.de/) does not autocomplete unless I press `Ctrl + Space`, which is a shortcut to change input method. How to change the shortcut for winefish autocompletion? Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: "Its first version was released
in 2005, and the latest stable version is 1.3.3, which is released 2006.
Many years have passed. Winefish is almost a zoombie... The original author
(Anh Kỳ Huỳnh) don't use TeX anymore; he has no time to support Winefish :("

Comment: @MartinSchröder Thanks! Is not it a open source program now?

Comment: Yes. And it's looking for a maintainer.